# Complex multidimensional array generate table

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

Hei guys,

**I have an array that looks like that:**

```
{
    "DEP_A": {
        "0": {
            "Austria": [
                {
                    "name": "NAME A",
                    "title": "TITLE A",
                    "email": "EMAIL A",
                    "phone": "PHONE A"
                }
            ],
            "rowspan": 1
        },
        "1": {
            "Croatia": [
                {
                    "name": "NAME AA",
                    "title": "TITLE AA",
                    "email": "EMAIL AA",
                    "phone": "PHONE AA"
                }
            ],
            "rowspan": 1
        },
        "rowspan": 2
    },
    "DEP_B": {
        "0": {
            "Austria": [
                {
                    "name": "NAME B",
                    "title": "TITLE B",
                    "email": "EMAIL B",
                    "phone": "PHONE B"
                }
            ],
            "rowspan": 1
        },
        "1": {
            "Croatia": [
                {
                    "name": "NAME BB",
                    "title": "TITLE BB",
                    "email": "EMAIL BB",
                    "phone": "PHONE BB"
                }
            ],
            "rowspan": 1
        },
        "rowspan": 2
    },
    "DEP_C": {
        "0": {
            "Croatia": [
                {
                    "name": "NAME C",
                    "title": "TITLE C",
                    "email": "EMAIL C",
                    "phone": "PHONE C"
                }
            ],
            "rowspan": 1
        },
        "rowspan": 1
    },
    "VAT DEP_D": {
        "0": {
            "Austria": [
                {
                    "name": "NAME D",
                    "title": "TITLE D",
                    "email": "EMAIL D",
                    "phone": "PHONE D"
                },
                {
                    "name": "NAME DD",
                    "title": "TITLE DD",
                    "email": "EMAIL DD",
                    "phone": "PHONE DD"
                }
            ],
            "rowspan": 2
        },
        "1": {
            "Croatia": [
                {
                    "name": "NAME DDD",
                    "title": "TITLE DDD",
                    "email": "EMAIL DDD",
                    "phone": "PHONE DDD"
                }
            ],
            "rowspan": 1
        },
        "2": {
            "Czech Republic": [
                {
                    "name": "NAME DDDD",
                    "title": "TITLE DDDD",
                    "email": "EMAIL DDDD",
                    "phone": "PHONE DDDD"
                },
                {
                    "name": "NAME DDDDD",
                    "title": "TITLE DDDDD",
                    "email": "EMAIL DDDDD",
                    "phone": "PHONE DDDDD"
                }
            ],
            "rowspan": 2
        }
        "rowspan": 5
    }
}
```

**The HTML output should be this:**

```
   <tr>
      <td rowspan="2">DEP_A</td>
      <td rowspan="1">AUSTRIA</td>
      <td>NAME A</td>
      <td>TITLE A</td>
      <td>EMAIL A</td>
      <td>PHONE A</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td rowspan="1">CROATIA</td>
      <td>NAME AA</td>
      <td>TITLE AA</td>
      <td>EMAIL AA</td>
      <td>PHONE AA</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td rowspan="2">DEP_B</td>
      <td rowspan="1">AUSTRIA</td>
      <td>NAME B</td>
      <td>TITLE B</td>
      <td>EMAIL B</td>
      <td>PHONE B</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td rowspan="1">CROATIA</td>
      <td>NAME BB</td>
      <td>TITLE BB</td>
      <td>EMAIL BB</td>
      <td>PHONE BB</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td rowspan="1">DEP_C</td>
      <td rowspan="1">CROATIA</td>
      <td>NAME C</td>
      <td>TITLE C</td>
      <td>EMAIL C</td>
      <td>PHONE C</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td rowspan="5">DEP_D</td>
      <td rowspan="2">AUSTRIA</td>
      <td>NAME D</td>
      <td>TITLE D</td>
      <td>EMAIL D</td>
      <td>PHONE D</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>NAME DD</td>
      <td>TITLE DD</td>
      <td>EMAIL DD</td>
      <td>PHONE DD</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td rowspan="1">CROATIA</td>
      <td>NAME DDD</td>
      <td>TITLE DDD</td>
      <td>EMAIL DDD</td>
      <td>PHONE DDD</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td rowspan="2">CZECH REPUBLIC</td>
      <td>NAME DDDD</td>
      <td>TITLE DDDD</td>
      <td>EMAIL DDDD</td>
      <td>PHONE DDDD</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>NAME DDDDD</td>
      <td>TITLE DDDDD</td>
      <td>EMAIL DDDDD</td>
      <td>PHONE DDDDD</td>
   </tr>
```

**The visual output looks like that:** https://prnt.sc/qtkqyl

**The code i've wrote:**

```
foreach($array as $key => $value){
        /////////////////////
        // COUNTRY COMPARE //
        /////////////////////
        if(isAssoc($b)){
            if($array[$key][$type] > 1){
                // HERE FAILS
            }else{
                //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
                // DONE -> IF COMPARE COUNTRIES BUT A COUNTRY DOESNT HAVE VALUE FOR SPECIFIC DEPARTMENT //
                //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
                $data .= "<tr>";
                    ////////////////
                    // DEPARTMENT //
                    ////////////////
                    $data .= "<td rowspan='" . $value[$type] . "'>" . $key . "</td>";

                    foreach($value as $k => $v){
                        /////////////
                        // COUNTRY //
                        /////////////
                        if(!is_numeric($v)){
                            $data .= "<td rowspan='" . $value[$type] . "'>" . $k . "</td>";
                        }

                        ////////////////////
                        // REST OF VALUES //
                        ////////////////////
                        foreach($v as $key_v => $value_v){
                            foreach($value_v as $kv => $vv){
                                $data .= "<td>" . $vv . "</td>";
                            }
                        }
                    }
                $data .= "</tr>";
            }

        ////////////////
        // NO COMPARE //
        ////////////////
        }else{
            //////////
            // DONE //
            //////////
            $data .= pretty_print('i should not enter here while multiple countries are selected');

            //////////////////////
            // IF MULTIPLE ROWS //
            //////////////////////
            if($array[$key][$type] > 1){
                $data .= "<tr>";
                    ////////////////
                    // DEPARTMENT //
                    ////////////////
                    $data .= "<td rowspan='" . $value[$type] . "'>" . $key . "</td>";

                    ///////////////////////
                    // REST OF FIRST ROW //
                    ///////////////////////
                    foreach($value[0] as $k => $v){
                        $data .= "<td>" . $v . "</td>";
                    }
                $data .= "</tr>";

                /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
                // REST OF MULTIPLE VALUES DEPARTMENT STARTING WITH SECOND //
                /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
                for($i = 1; $i < $array[$key][$type]; $i++){
                    $data .= "<tr>";
                        foreach($value[$i] as $k => $v){
                            $data .= "<td>" . $v . "</td>";
                        }
                    $data .= "</tr>";
                }
            ///////////////////
            // IF SINGLE ROW //
            ///////////////////
            }else{
                $data .= "<tr>";
                    ////////////////
                    // DEPARTMENT //
                    ////////////////
                    $data .= "<td rowspan='" . $value[$type] . "'>" . $key . "</td>";

                    ////////////////////
                    // REST OF VALUES //
                    ////////////////////
                    foreach($value as $k => $v){
                        foreach($v as $key_v => $value_v){
                            $data .= "<td>" . $value_v . "</td>";
                        }
                    }
                $data .= "</tr>";
            }
        }
    }
```

When it says in the code "**HERE FAILS**" i should create a `tr` with rowspan given in the array, thats easy... but if country has multiple values i should create a `td` with country's rowspan value, put the rest of the code (only the first values) then break the tr and create another one starting with the second value for that country that has many rows aaaand... i'm stuck... please, help?

**EDIT:** Forgot to add dependencies

```
function isAssoc(array $arr){
    if (array() === $arr) return false;
    return array_keys($arr) !== range(0, count($arr) - 1);
}

function pretty_print($array){
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    return "<pre>" . json_encode($array, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT) . "</pre>";
}
```